# How to change the color of the navigation bar in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, navigationbar

Like in the stack overflow navigation bar

if i click on questions the color of it should be change instead of orange line..

can anyone help?[image: colo change]

Comment: i guess you can add the color and background-color property to CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a listener on your button, and when you press it, change the color of it. 
You can do this for example :

```
var button = document.getElementById('myButton');
button.addEventListener('click', function(e) { 
  button.style.backgroundColor = "red";
});
```

You can also change the CSS class of your button instead of changing its color directly with javascript :

```
var button = document.getElementById('myButton');
button.addEventListener('click', function(e) { 
  button.className = 'selected';
});
```

CSS :

```
.selected
{
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Tell me if it helps you @KeerthiReddyYeruva

Comment: I have used css style. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with javascript like this:

```
document.getElementById("elementId").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Chrome as your web browser,you can open your console and copy the code below:

```
document.getElementById("nav-questions").style.backgroundColor = "red"
```

Then you can see the background color of the question Nav changed.[image]

[image]

Comment: when i click on other tab the style i snot reflecting

Comment: Each navigation tab has its own element ID,you should find out the ID,and then register the "change color "event when you click the tab.

Answer (score 0):

Try This answer

```js
function getElementById_Click() {
    document.getElementById("example").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

function getElementsByClassName_Click() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("example")[2].style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.example, #example {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="example ">
This is getElementsByClassName Example 1
</div>

<div id="example">
This is getElementById Example 
</div>
<div class="example">
This is getElementsByClassName Example 2
</div>
<div class="example">
This is getElementsByClassName Example 3
</div>
<div class="example">
This is getElementsByClassName Example 4
</div>

<button type="button" onclick="getElementById_Click()" >GET ELEMENT BY ID</button>
<button type="button" onclick="getElementsByClassName_Click()" >GET ELEMENT BY CLASS</button>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Keerthi Reddy Yeruva try this. hopeful this will work for you

Comment: this is in the same page @Faraz . I want to navigate to another page and the specific page tab should be highlighted